# How to fix Wine memory access violation

Tags: wine

I use Linux Mint 18.3. Recently I downloaded a game for Windows called SCP Containment Breach. I have managed to get it to run, but it crashes shortly afterwards during the loading screen and a small window pops up saying 'Memory access violation'.

I at first thought the problem was that I wasn't giving Wine enough memory, but even after using winetricks to increase the video memory Wine is permitted to access, I got the same error.

I have been trying to get it to work for ages now so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I was having that problem too on linux. I have looked everywhere on the internet to find a solution but I did not find one. So I decided to try to solve it myself.

**I have found a solution!**

It is simple, in the game directory there is an `options.ini` file.

- Just open it with any text editor
- Go down to where it says `enable vram = 0` and change it to `enable vram = 1`
- After that go to where it says `play startup video = true` and change it to `play startup video = false`.

It should work perfectly after that! If it did not work then just tell me and I will try to figure out another method.

You're Welcome!

-Fathergorgi

Comment: Thanks so much! I regret that I only saw this just today even though it's been here for ages! It works now! Who needs Windows?